# wait indicator while loading HttpWebRequest

Tags: wpf, httpwebresponse

here's my partial code

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
try
                {       
                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.site.my/install.php?data=" + uniqueID + "&pass=" + pass);
                    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishWebRequest), request);                   
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
}
private void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest).EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Display the content.
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            // Cleanup the streams and the response.
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();

            if (responseFromServer == "1")
            {
                MessageBox.show("ok")
            }else{
                MessageBox.show("no")
            }

        }
```

although i use async, it seems the window would 'hang' for a while.. so I think putting in a loading indicator would be good, right? where and how should i put it? i'm thinking of just a simple loading indicator, and not a progress bar..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use the code provided here http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/03/wpf-multithreading-using-the-backgroundworker-and-reporting-the-progress-to-the-ui/ to do a background worker and the application won't hang anymore

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's bad practice to put all this code in the constructor. Loaded event is a more proper place for this logic. Secondly, your question is quite vague: What sort of loading indicator do you have in mind? Do you want to write it yourself, or did you get a third-party one? What exactly are you trying to accomplish, what's the design of your GUI?